# Returning values from a PostgreSQL function

Tags: sql, postgresql, return-value

I have a function that loop a table and do processing returning values. I was returning SETOF `VARCHAR[]` and returning with `RETURN NEXT the_varchar_array` and worked fine.

But now I need to return some `INTEGER` before the `VARCHAR[]`.

How I can define the returning value to return the `INTEGER` value and the `VARCHAR[]` and how I returning they inside the function?

If a define as `RETURNS SETOF INTEGER, INTEGER, INTERGER, VARCHAR[]`, it don't works.

If I use `RETURNS TABLE(a INTEGER, b INTEGER, c INTEGER, d VARCHAR[])`, works, but I don't know how to return each value inside the function.

`RETURN NEXT a,b,c,d` doesn't works. Only `RETURN NEXT` return an empty line.

Comment: [This development documentation](http://developer.postgresql.org/pgdocs/postgres/xfunc-sql.html) at PostgreSQL shows the different ways to return values from functions. You might have to look into a composite return type or a row of data containing all of your values.

Comment: @Cory I used a composite type and solved my problem. Please, answer this question to select your answer.

Comment: I converted my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This development documentation](http://developer.postgresql.org/pgdocs/postgres/xfunc-sql.html) at PostgreSQL shows the different ways to return values from functions. You might have to look into a composite return type or a row of data containing all of your values.

*Note - comment converted to an answer at the OP's request*

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
RETURNS SETOF record
```

That should allow you to return any information you want.